# Placing a database within WinForm project and licensing options

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

We plan on pushing a windows application on computers external from our companies network (in various locations). I'm wondering what options I have for databases.  I'd like to use SQL Server, but is there a way to avoid paying for licenses for each PC we load the windows application on?

Also, is there a way to have the data part of the executable when deploying the application, or would I need to install SQL Server on each machine?

Thanks!

Comment: You usually have one database on the server and have clients connect to it. If you want each client to have its own database, take a look at [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx).

Comment: If your DB does not require heavy queries and multiuser access, you can use SQLite. It can be embedded in your app. It is free. Otherwise, you can add automatic installation of SQL Server Express with the setup of software. It can be installed silently and you don't need licenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid paying for licenses for each PC we load the windows application on?

Presumably you're just accessing a local database on these machines right? In that case you can use [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx). It's free and pretty darn good.

> Is there a way to have the data part of the executable when deploying the application?

If you're deploying your application via ClickOnce, then you can [set SQL Server Compact as a prerequisite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592943(v=sql.110).aspx) so the application will check for its presence and install it if needed.

Otherwise, you can push it out like any other prerequisite as part of the installer package (i.e. InstallShield or WiX).

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative and a bit newer technology to Sql Server Compact Edition, you could use [`LocalDB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx).

Both are MS SQL products, but `LocalDB` doesn't have the disadvantages of CE, is still a file based DB and doesn't require the server installation, configuration and maintenance of `SqlServer Express`, only the runtime components.

[Here](http://erikej.blogspot.in/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html) you can find a nice comparison between Express, Compact and LocalDB
and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx) you can find the introduction of LocalDB by Microsoft.

The licensing of LocalDB is the same as for SqlExpress and you also need an installer to run for the runtime components of LocalDB (which is one downside when compared to CE).